# Axios POST request passing an empty object to Spring REST API end doing

Tags: reactjs, spring-mvc, axios, spring-rest

I am in the middle of learning react/redux and decided to take an old JQuery UI that makes request to Spring REST API and rewrite it in React.  I am using Axios to make the request.  In my old Query UI , I do the following when a form is submitted.

```
 var formInputs = $(form).serialize();

 $.post("/addAttrItem",  formInputs,  function(updated){
                    refresh();
                    showRecord(updated);
                    displayControlMsg("Record below was added successfully");
                }
```

This is handled by the following code below in Spring

```
 @ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/someURL", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public AttrItem restfulAdd(AttrItem item) throws Exception
{
    item.setLastUpdate(new java.util.Date());
    itemService.create(item);
    return item;
}
```

When sending the request through JQuery, AttrItem item param populated with all right values sent in by JQuery

However when I try the following axios

```
    axios.post(someUrl, data).then
    (res => {
        dispatch(addAttributeSync(res));
    }).catch(error =>{
        alert('add item failed ' + error);
    }
```

the AttrItem item  param while not null itself, is empty with none of the fields set to values from the form. I confirmed that the data object contains right data prior to the post request.

Answer (score 2):

See if mapping the HTTP request body to the method argument `item` using `@RequestBody` annotation helps.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/someURL", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public AttrItem restfulAdd(@RequestBody AttrItem item) throws Exception
{
    item.setLastUpdate(new java.util.Date());
    itemService.create(item);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however just @RequestBody annotation didn't seem to help, I had to do other things as well.  Please  look my answer

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to have resolved the issue.  In React I added header config

```
 return dispatch => {
    var config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      };

    axios.post(someUrl, data).then
     (res => {
            dispatch(addAttributeSync(res));
      }).catch(error =>{
        alert('add item failed ' + error);
    }
```

And I modified my Spring Controller endpoint to set the consumes and produces attribute as follows.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/attributeItem", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public AttributeItem restfulAdd(@RequestBody AttributeItem attributeItem) throws Exception
{
    attributeItem.setLastUpdate(new java.util.Date());
    attributeItemService.create(attributeItem);
    return attributeItem;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see that you have defined `config` but you do not seem to be passing it or using it at all. Can you please explain as I am also facing similar issue.

Comment: I have posted my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71466221/7584240 Can you please have a look and provide some solution?