# Method is not being detected when using the Custom class as input parameter type for the REST API service

Tags: java, spring, rest, quarkus

I am developing a Web application using `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` which makes call to my Java Service using the `Axios` but during the call I get the error:

```
POST http://localhost:9001/generate 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I am getting this error because my Java service type accepts the input parameter of Custom data type `InputParameter`. If I change to `String` then it works fine. So I would like to know what changes should I make to front-end call or to my Java Service so it can work with `InputParameter type`.

Following is the Vuejs call that I am making to Java service:

```
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

this.$axios.post('/generate', { ...JSON.parse(inputParameter) }, { headers })
.then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data))
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Following is my Java service method which is NOT working with custom data type `InputParameter`, the call does not detect the method and execution does not go within the method:

```
@Path("/generate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "returns list of JSON Objects"),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal Server Error occurred")
})
public String generate(final InputParameter inputParameter){
    System.out.println(inputTemplate.toString());
    return null;
}
```

If I change the above JAVA Service method input parameter data type to String then the method is detected and input is printed:

```
@Path("/generate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "returns list of JSON Objects"),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal Server Error occurred")
})
public String generate(final String inputParameter){
    System.out.println(inputTemplate);
    return null;
}
```

I am not understanding whats wrong here. Can someone please help?

Things I have tried:

1. Adding `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.
2. Changing the method to `public String generate(@RequestBody final InputParameter inputParameter)`

My `InputParameter` class looks something like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InputParameter {
    private List<String> names;
    private List<String> jobs;
}
```

My InputParameter which I am passing to Java Service looks something like this:

```
{
  "names":[
    "Batman",
    "Superman",
    "Ironman"
  ],
  "jobs":[
    "Fighting",
    "Fyling",
    "Teching"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you also need `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`  .

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks a lot for the response I already tried that but did not work for me.

Comment: Would you show the InputParameter class from both front end and back end!

Comment: @Rafa Thanks a lot for the response. I have modified my question and added the inputs, please check and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer can be helpful to someone else in the future. I tried some things but nothing worked and finally following worked for me:

```
@POST
@Path("/generate")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@APIResponses(value = {
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "returns list of JSON Objects"),
        @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal Server Error occurred")
})
public String generate(final InputParameter inputParameter){
    System.out.println(inputTemplate.toString());
    return null;
}
```

There was also one small setting that I had to change related to `Jackson ObjectMapper` which is not relevant here because it's my project-specific that I missed in another class. Maybe that was the issue I was facing. Now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Dear in the back end the api is accepting an object of type InputParameter. For solving the problem you have to create a class the same as InputParameter class and generate an object of that and send that object to the back end.

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Actually, I already have the class `InputParameter` and the data which is coming as input to this method has all the values as per the `InputParameter` class. So I am a bit confused about what you are suggesting here. Can you please elaborate more or maybe give me a simple example for clear understanding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the inputStream on the front end?

Comment: I have added the JSON in the question that's actually coming in as an input to the method.

Comment: Thats the input stream which I am giving to my method.

Comment: have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743918/axios-post-request-passing-an-empty-object-to-spring-rest-api-end-doing

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Actually, I have tried all the things provided but for some reason, everything is failing. I have tried adding the `@ResponseBody` as well. Please let me know what I should do further.

Comment: can you upload the back end project to github?

Comment: Thanks a lot for willing to help. Actually, I tried something similar and for some reason, it worked now. Thanks a lot again for the help. I will post the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Can you explain what was the problem so we learn too.

Comment: Surely, I would be happy to share. I have added the code as an answer. Actually, I was missing one set in my Jackson ObjectMapper `.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())`. Maybe due to this, method was not getting detected.